# MongoDB Java - update a field in a record

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I would like to update a field of a record which has been already been stored in the database. How can I achieve that? All of the examples I've come across so far are either in Python/Php or an older version of MongoDB (Java) and the api is not longer current.

Basically I would like to load an object with a particular userId in memory and change its username value. (I'd like to refer you to the code below)

Thank you so much

EDIT

So far I've got the following code:

```
public class UserDAO {
    MongoOperations mongoDb;

    public UserDAO(){
        mongoDb = MongoDBInstanceFactory.getMongoDBinstance();
    }

    public User getUserByUsername(String username){
        Query searchUserQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("username").is(username));
        return mongoDb.findOne(searchUserQuery, User.class);
    }

    public User getUserById(String id){
        Query searchUserQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
        return mongoDb.findOne(searchUserQuery, User.class);
    }

    public User addUser(String username){
        mongoDb.save(new User(username));
        return getUserByUsername(username);
    }
}

   @Document(collection = "users")
   public class User {

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public User() {
    }
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;

    //getter, setter, toString, Constructors
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser")
public @ResponseBody
String registerUser(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

sb = new StringBuilder();

user = userDao.getUserByUsername(username);

if (user == null) {
    user = userDao.addUser(username);
    userQueryPhaseDao.addUserQueryPhase(user.getId(), null, "0");
    sb.append("1|").append(user.getId());
    response.addCookie(new Cookie("userId", user.getId()));
} else {
    sb.append("0|User with that handle already exists!");
}

return sb.toString();
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you have your own three lines that you thought might have worked but failed?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed. I've written a DAO whereby I created wrapper for addUser and getUserById methods, however, am not sure how to do an update. So pasting those lines here won't be of much help :/

Comment: It will show other people that you really spent time and make them more sympathetic to your problem.

Comment: Ok you're right. I've edited my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change an existing document, use the method [`DBCollection.update`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#update%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29).

The method takes two parameters.

The first parameter tells MongoDB which document to update. It works exactly like `find` or `findOne`.

The second is the document that document will be replaced with. When you only want to update a single field and not replace the whole document, you need to use the [`$set` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).